# Simple way to merge line to line git conflict

Tags: git, github

Am facing a lots of problem with solving a git conflict,

Its easy if there are less files are conflict and we are able to merge them by comparing,
But in Case of large no of files are conflicted and i want to solved the conflict at my local set up what is best solution for same?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any external merge tool for that. Ethier run it externally or via the `git mergetool` command which launches whatever is set as your default merge tool (config parameter merge.tool) or any which you provide via the --tool option. [more info on mergetool](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mergetool.html)

There are many possible merge/diff applications for that, and I don't want to favor one in particular over another.